# C - Memory mapping

Tags: c, memory

I have two questions:

1)if I have a file which contains for example some numbers, like:

```
  4 5 6 7
```

or some words like:

```
  home sun cat dog
```

Can I map it into a region of memory? Or it can be done only for binary files?

2)Mapping is useful even if the file is small?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) All files are binary files... but some of them can also be considered something easier to work with. (That is, yes, you can map your text files too but the memory will contain text, not numbers.)

2) Mapping can be useful or not, depending on exactly what you're doing with it / what your reason for mapping it to memory is. If your reason is efficient reading, you probably gain nothing (and lose nothing) on small files. If your reason is simple direct access to the file by code that doesn't even know it's dealing with a file, then certainly it's useful even for small files.

Comment: As regards the first answer, I did not understand what you mean when you say:  "you can map your text files too but the memory will contain text, not numbers".

Comment: What I meant there is that the data will be mapped exactly (as text)... so if you were to point, for example, an `int *` at the memory containing "4 5 6 7" it would not dereference to the number 4. It would dereference to the ascii value for '4' instead.

Comment: so if I want to read the number 4 from the memory mapped how can i do?

Comment: Since you know the data is character data, assuming you have `char *p` pointing at the '4' in your map, and assuming you want to read it as an int and you have `int num;`, you would `sscanf(p, "%d", &num);`

Comment: Ok,thank you for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can map it into a region of memory. Wether it is useful or not depends on your usecase.

You seem to be a bit confused about what is a binary file... for a computer all files are "binary", in the sense they're just a list of bytes. What we call non-binary files are usually the files which are human-readable, meaning the value of the bytes they contain are displayed as letters, numbers and other readable symbols.

Then, on some OS (windows), if you open a file as non-binary some special handling is made when you write a newline character ('\n') to the file. What happens is that the implementations adds a return character ('\r') before the newline, because on windows line endings are "\r\n" instead of "\n" like on other OSes. Note that '\n' and '\r' are just values like 'a' or 'b' or '!' are, they all are in the range 0-255 (values storable in an unsigned char).

Answer (score -1):

Usually  all files are mapped into memory for simply viewing or processing. From memory OS will send data to CPU or other hardware devices. Mapping is necessary regardless of files size.